# Как узнать используемую версию JS?

Tags: javascript

Мне приходится писать некоторые вещи, используя JS\jQuery. Проблема в том, что я пишу для некоторого приложения, в котором есть веб интерфейс.
Т.е. грубо говоря, бразуером для меня является именно это приложение.
Тестировать мне, конечно же, проще в браузере. В процессе работы натыкаюсь на такие вещи когда в chrome\opera работает, а в самом приложении нет.
Есть ли какая то возможность точно узнать версию\спецификацию языка, что бы сразу сложилось понимание какие вещи будут работать а какие нет?
Что то вроде аналога `phpinfo()`

Comment: Сомневаюсь, так как браузеры реализуют спецификации по частям и по-разному. Приложение определённо использует какой-то веб-движок для работы - лучше выясните версию этого движка; вероятно, это какой-нибудь Internet Explorer (если речь про Windows-приложение)

Comment: Попробуйте получить User-agent, если конечно он прописан
https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/

Или через Hex редактор поискать библиотеки в исполняемом файле

Возможно там используется Qt WebKit/Qt WebEngine

Comment: @AlexanderChernin в чем смысл постить ссылку на текущий вопрос?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вот теперь правильно ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271566/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-javascript-im-using

Comment: @Axifive достал я юзер агент, но как мне теперь понять какая версия ES поддерживается? Можно ли это понять по версиям Safari\AppleWebkit? Или с такими вопросами напрямую к разработчикам `SoftName` ?
Непосредственно сам user-agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) SoftName/6.3.40.2 Safari/537.21`

Comment: К сожалению по юзерагенту не понять. Либо к разработчику обратитесь, либо можете попробовать запустить скрипты проверяющие на es5, es6: https://www.bram.us/2016/10/31/checking-if-a-browser-supports-es6 https://gist.github.com/CityRay/c56e4fa874af9370cc1a367bd43095b0